# Про scroll и его внешний вид

Tags: css, прокрутка

Помогите, плиз, изменить классический вид вертикального scrollа на обычную тонкую линию.

```
<div class="scroll>
     <p>
          // тескт
     </p>
</div> 
<style>
.scroll{
     overflow: scroll;
     overflow-x: unset;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот смотри, вроде все учел. Цвета/размеры меняй как пожелаешь https://jsfiddle.net/ge4fsukh/9

```
<div class="body">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <br>
  <br>

    <textarea class="body" rows="5">
  lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem   lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem   lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem   lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem   lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem   lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem   lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem   lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem   lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem 
  </textarea>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>lalalalalalaa</p>
  <br>
</div>

.body {
  width: 100%;
}

$light-gray: #acacac !default;
$bg-gray: #ccc!default;
$medium-gray: #ddd !default;
$bg-gray: #bbb !default;

$scrollbar-size: 5px !default;
$scrollbar-size-textarea: 4px !default;



::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 $scrollbar-size rgba($light-gray,0.3);
  background-color: $light-gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: $scrollbar-size;
  height: $scrollbar-size;
  background-color: $light-gray;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: $medium-gray;
}

select,
textarea {
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: $scrollbar-size-textarea;
    background-color: $bg-gray;
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 $scrollbar-size-textarea rgba($bg-gray,0.3);
    background-color: $bg-gray;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, webkit-стилизация не работает в IE, Edge и Firefox. Посему, если нужно кроссбраузерное решение, лучше использовать скрипты. На сегодняшний день существует множество решений на JS, от себя могу порекомендовать [Malihu custom scrollbar](https://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Готовых стилей для него [предостаточно](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html) + всегда можно настроить вывод с помощью обычного CSS.

Накидал пример с его использованием - https://jsfiddle.net/Denisdude/rL8sqv9w/

```
$(".scroll-content").mCustomScrollbar();
```

Главное, не забудьте дать контейнеру максимальную высоту и подключить все файлы плагина.